# Dont have basic and empty activities in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

When try to create new project dont have any basic activities in templates. I only see templates with word "views" in it. Im very new to android studio and android development in general, and i cant normally learn from guides, cause difference in structure between templates is too confusing.

[image: Screenshot of templates]

I reinstalled android studio but still dont have neither empty activity or basic activity. What should i do to get these basic templates?

Comment: Scroll down , there is option for empty activity. Otherwise you can move forward with `No Activity` as creating an activity is just a matter of few seconds.

Comment: The "Views" ones are the ones that older tutorials describe.

Comment: me too. I hope to have a tutorial, but the tutorial let me choose basic activity. I can't get it.
the tutorial is https://developer.android.com/codelabs/build-your-first-android-app-kotlin#2